# Events from several buttons on the form

Tags: web.py

On the template has several button. Will look like the click event of these buttons?
Examples of more complex http://webpy.org/form#introduction with several buttons not found.

Comment: what exactly do u want? please post your question or doubts clearly.

Comment: How to do that by pressing the button1 worked Event1, pressing the button2 Event2, etc. A lot of buttons, they are all on the same form.